# VIM compiled from source unable to reconise python, YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python (2.6+ or 3.3+) support

Tags: python, vim, youcompleteme

I want to set up my vim on ubuntu 14.04 to work with YCM. Following the installation instructions I reallized that the native vim on 14.04 does not support YCM, therefore I exactly followed the instructions on how to install vim from source [here](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source), also changing the python config-dir to the correct ones.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 13 2016 11:04:57)
Included patches: 1-82
Compiled by ...@ubuntu
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
+balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
+browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +timers
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +title
+clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +toolbar
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        -perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +wildignore
```

It seems like it is installed with correct support for python? I have tried multiple times now but I can't get it to work. Still, when I open vim I get this error:

```
YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python (2.6+ or 3.3+) support
```

Comment: what doesn't work exactly? show us an error message or something else and most of all, keep trying!

Comment: Sorry, its in the question header.

Comment: when you followed the steps in the build-from-src notes (https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source), did you see and follow step # 3?  seems relevant.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the version of Vim that you compiled, and not still running the system Vim?

Comment: Actually, I tried it one more time, and of course it worked now. I think the problem was I installed vim with more dependencies than I had support for.

Comment: sudo apt install vim-nox [See this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12827/how-to-install-vim-with-python-support-for-debian-strech)